# The domain and search options in resolv.conf

Tags: networking, resolv.conf

Let's say you have a resolv.conf file that's something like this.

```
nameserver 192.168.0.7
nameserver 192.168.0.8
domain somedomain.local
```

Then let's say you just changed it to this.

```
nameserver 192.168.0.7
nameserver 192.168.0.8
search somedomain.local
```

Would these both do the same thing? Is one slightly better than the other?

Why would declaring both a domain and search not be recommended?